# Flexcard Datatable not showing icon

Tags: datatable, omnistudio

I am trying to add an icon to the flexcard datatable cell.
There is an option to choose the data type as an icon. but I just can't make it work.

Sample data I used:

```
{

  "flexcard_datatable": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Item 1",
      "description": "Description for Item 1",
      "status": "Active",
      "icon": "utility:success"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Item 2",
      "description": "Description for Item 2",
      "status": "Inactive",
      "icon": "utility:error" 
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Item 3",
      "description": "Description for Item 3",
      "status": "Active",
      "icon": "{!utility:success}"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Item 4",
      "description": "Description for Item 4",
      "status": "Pending",
      "icon": "{utility:clock}" 
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "Item 5",
      "description": "Description for Item 5",
      "status": "Active",
      "icon": "{!/resource/custom_domain__Dollar_sign_income}"
    }
  ]
}
```

It looks like:
[image]